# Visual Studio is unable to retrieve the service 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Authentication.IAzureRMTenantService'

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

When i click Deploy, I get  below error:
Visual Studio is unable to retrieve the service 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Authentication.IAzureRMTenantService'

Answer (score 1):

With just this error message , we will not be able to troubleshoot .

Someone from the community also reported the same issue , and he was able to resolve this issue by doing below work around

Workaround is to Sign out of Visual Studio by resetting the complete data. Once logged into Windows, launch Visual Studio - DO NOT SIGN IN. Open the solution, right click on the Deployment project. it should work.

here is a similar thread on the same issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3ce280c2-2ad8-4627-be6a-fba9dbb3c835/systeminvalidoperationexception-user-account-needs-to-be-authenticated-before-calling?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Though the team is right now focusing on to resolve major issue with higher customer impact, if the workaround doesn't work for you, i would suggest you to report this issue in forum. you can see the details here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/report-a-problem?view=vs-2017#faq

also please provide as much detail as possible, it will help us to resolve the issue quickly.

Comment: I reinstalled the azure logic app extension for visual Studio. Then issue got resolved.